# Magento 2 installation setup wizard error

Tags: magento2

I have cloned Magento 2 using `git clone https://github.com/Magento/Magento2.git`
and installed using `composer install` command
Now I am facing some issue at the time of Setup wizard Add a database an Internal error is  displayed in access.log 
[image]

This image shows access log entry which shows internal server error
[image]

### My Server Setup

Ubuntu 18
PHP 7.2
Mysql 5

Comment: please see `var/log/exceprion.log` you will get error Here

Answer (score 0):

Dont clone from git

This is for development if you plan to submit pull requests

Either

`composer create-project --prefer-source --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.3.3 ./`

Or

Download zip from downloads section in magento website